# How do you use the elytra?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

1.9 added a set of glider wings for us to use. Now that I have an elytra, how do I use it?

Answer (score 6):

In order to activate the glider feature of the elytra, you need to have it equipped in the chest piece slot, jump off a cliff face, and press space in midair. It is imperative that you press space again, since simply jumping is not enough.

Comment: Or instead of space, whatever the jump button is.

Comment: Well, yes, if you've rebound jump, it'll be whatever button that is